IQ puzzle with 7x7 grid of numbers, some single-digit ones a different color














6
1
29
9
14
89
3


12
7
64
35
2
11
10


2
87
91
62
72
99
32


37
13
45
4
24
84
2


55
4
34
14
26
49
92


16
85
17
91
?
77
0


5
27
2
66
14
53
37



Which number, 0-5, replaces the question mark?
Original image. Source: https://www.treningmozga.com/

Could you perhaps provide a link to the test?

@PDT The website URL is included in the screenshot, is that enough or does there need to be a physical link?

No it’s just that the test itself might provide some context that may aid solving this puzzle
